# jqgrid addrowdata problem

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with adding a new empty row in a jqgrid.

My colmodel is :

```
colModel: [{ name: 'recid', index: 'testid', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true} },
           { name: 'JobTask.Id', index: 'JobTask.Id', hidden: true },
           { name: 'InvolvedParty.Id', index: 'InvolvedParty.Id', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true} },
           { name: 'InvolvedParty.Lastname', index: 'InvolvedParty.Lastname', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true},
           { name: 'deletefield', width: 100, sortable: false, title: false, align: 'center', label: ' '}],
```

The code I use to insert the row is:

```
var rowid = jQuery.Guid.New();
var newRowData = [{ "recid": rowid, "JobTask.Id": "@(Model.id)", "InvolvedParty.Id": "", "InvolvedParty.Lastname": "", "deletefield": ""}];
$("#grid_id").addRowData(rowid, newRowData);
```

then I enter some data and save the row with

```
jQuery('#grid_id').saveRow(rowid);
```

everything works fine. Now when I press the insert again, I get an empty
row with just one cell, which is not even editable. My newly inserted row
should had two fields ***lastname*** and the ***deletefield*** which contains two buttons (delete, save).

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try instead of that

```
var newRowData = [{ "recid": rowid, "JobTask.Id": "@(Model.id)", "InvolvedParty.Id": "", "InvolvedParty.Lastname": "", "deletefield": ""}];
```

doing :

```
var newRowData = { "recid": rowid, "JobTask.Id": "@(Model.id)", "InvolvedParty.Id": "", "InvolvedParty.Lastname": "", "deletefield": ""};
```

- if this won't work , make sure that added rows for sure have different ids
- you can also try reloading after adding new row by `trigger(“reloadGrid”)`

hope that will help i have no more ideas

**EDIT :**

ok i now what was wrong

from jqgrid wiki :

> ... This method can insert multiple
>   rows at once. In this case the data
>   parameter should be array defined as 
>   [{name1:value1,name2: value2…},
>   {name1:value1,name2: value2…} ] and
>   the first option rowid should contain
>   the name from data object which should
>   act as id of the row. It is not
>   necessary that the name of the rowid
>   in this case should be a part from
>   colModel.

that meens you should be able also to use [] like that :

```
var newRowData = [{ "recid": rowid, "JobTask.Id": "@(Model.id)", "InvolvedParty.Id": "", "InvolvedParty.Lastname": "", "deletefield": ""}];

$("#grid_id").addRowData("recid", newRowData);
```

Comment: yes you are correct about the edit post, it works that way too, thank you again.