# jqgrid external control example

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, external-process

I'm new to JQ and JQ grid. I recenly got my admin all set up with jqgrid..it looks great. Now I want to add a few forms to the front of the site and I can NOT get a clear understanding on 'external controls'. I want a stand alone form not attached to a grid

This answer was offered, but I have no idea what to do with it.
What part of the external control is this:ise

```
$("#id").jqGrid ('searchGrid', {multipleSearch:true, overlay: false});
```

Really, the confusion between the 'myfirstgrid' tutorial and the jqGrid Demos is exausting.

Would some one be so kind to supply a small working model of a form ADD not attached to the grid. The grid is great, but I want to have a clean form to enter the data.

Ex:
page.html (including all of the JQ)
page.php

I've seen small examples, but none concerning this external control request.
You could use this code i suppose and simply add the control, I could probably get it from there:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/editing_data/add_new_row/default.php#HTMLContent

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the built in add row form if you don't like. You can always create your own form elsewhere on the page and use it to add rows to the jqGrid programatically using the `addRowData` method.

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740742/jqgrid-addrowdata-problem) to see an example of how to use `addRowData` correctly.